# Return Multiple Values on Passing Arguments via AJAX, PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, ajax, jquery

I am developing ajax Based Search , This is demo of how it will be. I am faceing Problem in returning result. I need to show the Result 2 times. But its only showing once. Below is my HTML code

```
<form action="" method="post" id="demoform">
<select style="width:250px;padding:5px 0px;color:#f1eedb;"  name="product" class="product">
   <option>TENNIS</option>
   <option>FOOTBALL</option>
   <option>SWIMMING</option>
</select>
</form>
<div id="result">Display Result Here</div>
```

I Using The Below Ajax Script to Retrieve Data :-

```
$(".product").change(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type : 'POST',
                url : 'post.php',
                dataType : 'json',
                data: {
                    product : $(".product option:selected").text(),
                },
                success : function(data){
                    $('#result').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                        .html(data.msg).show();
                    if (data.error === true)
                        $('#demoForm').show();
                },
                error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    $('#result').removeClass().addClass('error')
                        .text('There was an error.').show(500);
                    $('#demoForm').show();
                }
            });
        });
```

The post.php file has the following code :-

```
<?php
require('connect.php');
$get_select = $_POST[product];
if($get_product!='FOOTBALL'){
  $return['error'] = true;
  return['msg'] = 'Incorrect Selection';
  echo json_encode(return);
}
else {
  $return['error'] = false;
  $i=0;
  while($i<2) {
    return['msg'] = $get_product;
  }
  echo json_encode(return);//Returns only one result.
}
?>
```

I need to show the result Two times as "CRICKET CRICKET", but its only showing once. 
What should i do to get both the result.

Comment: I have a few questions on the PHP: (1) $get_product does not exist - do you mean $get_select? (2) all of those places where you say 'return' do you mean '$return'? (3) why are you putting $get_product into $return['msg'] twice - is that where you think you'll get both results? If you select 'FOOTBALL' you should get back something to the effect of {'error':'false','msg':'FOOTBALL'}.

Comment: @adwitya-media Take look at the answers and mark the correct one please :)

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that this line is confusing php:

> while($i<2) {
>       return['msg'] = $get_product;
>     }

Should it be $return? Using a reserved word like 'return' is a tad iffy too.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the following code:

```
else {
  $i=0;
  $messageToReturn = "";
  while($i<2) {
    $messageToReturn .= $get_product; //Append to your variable
  }
  return json_encode($messageToReturn); //Returns the result
}
```

I would suggest to change the while to a for loop.
In that case you will get this:

```
else {
 $messageToReturn = "";
 for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
 {
    $messageToReturn .= $get_product; //Append to your variable
 }
 return json_encode($messageToReturn);
```

If you know the times you need to repeat, use a for loop. The while is never ending. So you can get a possible stack overflow...